# Parse nested CSV columns into new CSV rows

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a CSV file which contains 3 columns of CSV data "nested" within it. I want to split the contents of those CSV columns out to make a new row for each CSV item, add a sequence number to each item (which corresponds to the order of the item in the sequence within the CSV columns), and then add a corresponding ItemID number that corresponds to the CSV column that it came from. I need to take what looks like Table1 below and make it look like Table2.

Table1 (the original CSV file).  First row is column names:

```
StoreID,Date,StoreName,City,State,Category1CSV,Category2CSV,Category3CSV
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,"Flour,Yeast,Baking Powder","Milk,Water,Oil","Cinnamon,Sugar"
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,"Baking Powder,Yeast,Four","Oil,Milk,Water"
```

[image: Table1 original CSV file]

Table2 (after splitting the CSV column contents). First row is column names:

```
StoreID,Date,StoreName,City,State,ItemName,ItemRank,ItemCategory
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Flour,1,1
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Yeast,2,1
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Baking Powder,3,1
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Milk,4,2
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Water,5,2
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Oil,6,2
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Cinnamon,7,3
1051,2/16/2014,Easton,Columbus,OH,Sugar,8,3
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,Baking Powder,1,1
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,Yeast,2,1
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,Flour,3,1
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,Oil,4,2
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,Milk,5,2
1425,1/14/2014,Crocker Park,Westlake,OH,Water,6,2
```

[image: Table2 after parsing the CSV columns]

The Table 1 columns labeled Category1CSV, Category2CSV, and Category3CSV contents map to Table 2 columns: ItemName, ItemRank, ItemCategory, where:

- ItemName is the Item (example: Flour),
- ItemRank is the order of the item in the CSV list, and
- ItemCategory is either 1,2 or 3, depending on whether the data came from Category1CSV, Category2CSV or Category3CSV.

The most important aspect of this is to maintain the order of items from within the CSV columns as they get split to new rows. For example, StoreID 1051 has Category1CSV contents of "Flour,Yeast,Baking Powder". Those will map to the columns ItemName, ItemRank (the sequence number), and ItemCategory such that ItemName = Flour, it's ItemRank = 1, and the ItemCategory = 1. This would be the first row in Table 2. The second row would be ItemName = Yeast, it's ItemRank = 2, and the ItemCategory = 1, and so on until you end up with what looks like Table 2 above. Also, you'll notice that the ItemRank numbering starts with the contents of the column Category1CSV, then continues to Category2CSV and finally Category3CSV.

Not all rows in the original CSV file have items in all 3 CSV columns. For example, Store 1051 had items in all 3 Categories, but store 1425 only had items in Category 1 and 2. Other stores might only have items in 1 Category. Some logic would need to take that into consideration when it's processing the file.

My CSV file contains a couple thousand rows. The resulting file will probably have tens-of-thousands of rows.

How can I do this?

Comment: This looks like a very messy question, would you mind formatting so its easier to read? Also provide your code and point out what's the problem you are having.

Comment: @DanielJimenez, It's kind of a messy problem.  I don't have any code at this point.  All I have are the CSV files.  How would you like me to reformat it?  The tables are the only thing I could format in here.

Comment: It is just very hard to follow. Also i don't think users appreciate when you expect them to just write you code.

Comment: @DanielJimenez, I have zero experience with Python, which is why I don't have any code to share to the group.  It's not like I'm being lazy.  I'm reading a couple of O'Reilly books to learn. I have just got Python 3.4 and PyCharm installed today.  I agree, it is hard to follow... I will try to make it easier.  I just need to take what looks like formatting in Table1 and make it look like the formatting in Table2.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to spend hours creating code for me.  If someone can at least help me get started I'd appreciate it.  I've tried to solve this other ways, with Excel macros and SQL, but it seems that one of Python's strengths is parsing and working with CSV, XML, etc.  I learned that just last night, so I'm excited to see what Python can do.  If anyone can at least get me started, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To point you in the right direction:

- The module you're looking for is Python's helpful [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module. Have a look at the docs for it - there are some good examples walking you through parsing an input file (of any size and structure) and converting to various Python objects.
- Happily, your 'empty row' thing is a non-problem. The csv module will recognise two commas (or whatever other delimiter you choose) as an empty string and act as you'd expect it to.

As Daniel has indicated, I'm afraid I'm not entirely clear on what your worries are in the explanatory paragraphs in your question, but I'm confident that if you take some time playing about with the module you'll find you can get it to work as you'd hoped.

Comment: I'm looking at the csv module.Fantastic!  My main worry was maintaining the order of items in those CSV columns as they get split into rows, and adding a sequence number that corresponds to that order.  For example, StroreID 1051 has Category1CSV contents of "Flour,Yeast,Baking Powder". Those will map to the columns ItemName, ItemRank (the sequence number), and ItemCategory such that ItemName = Flour, it's ItemRank = 1, and the ItemCategory = 1. This would be the first row in Table 2. The second row would be ItemName = Yeast, it's ItemRank = 2, and the ItemCategory = 1, and so on

Comment: Ok; good news, as you have nothing to worry about. I suggest you try and end up with a list of dictionaries, which csv.DictReader will help with admirably. Lists are ordered, and your data will have the same order in the list as it did in your document.

Comment: It's starting to make sense, I think.  I need a list because dictionary objects are not ordered, but list objects are, but the dictionary key pairs helps solve the problem of what column they come from.